# django object.id does not work when passed in an url in html

Tags: django, django-templates

I have just started learning Django and I cannot figure out why my player.id kills the page when I try to pass it in an url, while it does work as a variable (see both in the code below.) When I omit the player.id from the url, the page works (except for the "delete" link, of course).

```
{% for player in all_players%}
<li>{{player.player_name|capfirst}} scored {{player.player_score}} and the id {{player.id}}!</li>
<div class="link" id="link"> <a href="{% url 'delete' player.id %}"> delete </a></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is my urls and "delete" in view:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('first', views.first, name='first'),
    path('delete/int:player_id', views.delete, name='delete'),
    path('third', views.third, name='third'),
    path('second/int:player_id', views.second, name='second'),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

```
def delete(request, player_id): 
  player = Player.players_objects.get(id=player_id)
  player.delete()
  return render(request, 'all_players.html', {'player': player})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your urlpatterns like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('first', views.first, name='first'),
    path('delete/<int:player_id>/', views.delete, name='delete'),
    path('third', views.third, name='third'),
    path('second/<int:player_id>/', views.second, name='second'),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Checkout [Django Documentation URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/) for more detail.